# Given an Ethereum account hash, is it possible to tell whether it is a "normal" account or a contract account?

Tags: ethereum

Ethereum has two types of accounts, “normal” (think Bitcoin) and contracts. Given only a hash, is it possible to tell which type an account is?

Answer (score 0):

Both types have hashes of the same length, so that’s not enough. Contract-type accounts have a “data” attribute while “normal” accounts do not. Use “web3.eth.getCode()”. If that method returns “0x”, you’re dealing with an account. Anything more than that means it’s a contract.

Not currently possible in Solidity.